# Add progressbar at bottom of a listview

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, infinite-scroll

I'm creating a simple listview with an endless scroll effect.
While I'm downloading new data I want to display an indeterminate progressbar at the bottom of the listview (like gmail app).

There is 2 solutions

- Add the progressbar as a an item of my listview, but I don't like this solution
- Add the progressbar at the bottom of my listview and show/hide it

It would give something like that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/trobber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/List_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the progressbar is not displayed when my list is longuer than the size of my screen (in other words when I have to scoll).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use instead yourListView.[addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)(put your ProgressBar View)

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time !

Comment: After adding FooterView to my listview I am getting class cast exception when I try to set an adapter to the listView??

Comment: hello you got solution for this..??

Comment: @codeRider This is a problem in older versions of android e.g. JellyBean.

Answer (score 2):

To be elaborated, here's how you do it:

A. Create a layout xml file, name it as progress_bar_footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

B. In your activity,

```
View mProgressBarFooter = ((LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.progress_bar_footer, null, false);
```

C. Use it.

```
listView.addFooterView(mProgressBarFooter); //or
listView.removeFooterView(mProgressBarFooter);
```

Credit goes to this [John Moses' page](https://coderwall.com/p/o2nggg/quick-and-dirty-loading-row-in-android-listview).